# System of differential equations with integral condition

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to solve differential equations of the following type

$$
f'(y)= A(y)f(y),
$$
where $y \in D$, $f: D \subseteq \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^n$, $A: D \to  \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ subject to $\int_{D} f_j(y) dy =1$, $j=1,...,n$. Is there any theory known for solving equations of this type, i.e. any existence and uniqueness theory?

Comment: What do you know about $D$? Is it open? An interval?

Comment: I think an idea for an existence/uniqueness theory is to write the general solution $f=\sum c_i \phi_i$ (follows from linearity), then solve the system of equations $\sum_i \left ( \int_D (\phi_i)_j dy \right ) c_i = 1$ for $c_i$. Then the only question is whether the matrix $B_{ij}=\int_D (\phi_i)_j dy$ is invertible.

Answer (score 0):

To answer this, it is useful to know that

(1) there will be a vector-valued parameter for the general solution

(2) the integral over $D$ of $f$ will depend continuously on these parameters, and

(3) (a) it is easy to see that the $f=0$ is a solution, which also has 0 for the integral, while (b) there will be solutions where this integral will be arbitrarily large.  So existence should be guaranteed.

Uniqueness on the other hand, maybe.  You have $n$ parameters, and $n$ constraints, so uniqueness is possible.  However, the constraint equations, while continuous on the parameters, are nonlinear in general, so there will not be a general theory to determine uniqueness.

Comment: There are $n$ scalar constraints, one for each component of $f$.

Comment: That's right, I will edit.

Answer (score 0):

You got a homogeneous linear system. Its solution can be written via a fundamental matrix as 
$$
f(y)=\Phi(y)f(a).
$$
Your condition then translates as
$$
{\bf 1}=\int_a^b\Phi(y)dy·f(a)
$$
and you get the usual conditions on solvability. Since $\Phi(a)=I$ the system matrix is invertible if $b$ is close enough to $a$, for general intervals, anything could happen.